# How can I avoide XSD sequence when generating XSDs from JAX-WS?

Tags: java, xsd, jax-ws, sequence

When I have annotaded java class like

```
@javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class UserdataType {

    String username;
    String street;
    String address;
```

it will be generated to

```
<xs:complexType name="userdataType">
<xs:sequence>
<xs:element name="username" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
<xs:element name="street" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
<xs:element name="address" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
```

So, by default JAX-WS always generates 'sequences' in XSD files.

This forces the clients to take care of the exact order the elements, which is not helpful in some cases.

Is there a way to generate something different then sequences?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add an [`XmlType`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlType.html) annotation with an empty `propOrder`, like this:

```
 @XmlType(propOrder={})
```

It will then generate an `xs:all` (which is unordered) instead of a sequence.

```
<xs:complexType name="userdataType">
  <xs:all>
    <xs:element name="username" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
    <xs:element name="street" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
    <xs:element name="address" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
  </xs:all>
</xs:complexType>
```

Comment: Now it would be nice to have it the other way around. `xjc` is generating a fixed `propOrder` even if the input file uses `<all>` instead of `<sequence>`.